# Change font size with cups and python

Tags: python, fonts, size

I print a txt file with cups and python.
How do I change the font size?

```
conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
printer_name = list(printers.keys())[0]
conn.printFile(printer_name,'file.txt','',{})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it worked for me...

```
conn.printFile(printer_name,'file.txt','',{'landscape':'True', 'cpi':'14', 'lpi':'10'})
```

BTW I added the `'landscape':'True'` to show that you can pass additional info in case needed